# R: Error in model.frame.default(form = variable lengths differ (found for 'excel')

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, r-caret

I am using a for loop, and I need to predict multiple columns and store them the same time.

cols is a vector containing all the columns I need to predict, mat is data.frame (my text features basically).

df is main dataframe having text, and prediction columns.

```
for (colm in cols){
  label <- as.factor(df[[colm]])
  dfm <- mat
  dfm[[colm]] <- label

  #Boruta(as.factor(colm)~., data=dfm, pValue = 0.01, mcAdj = TRUE, maxRuns = 20,
  #       doTrace = 2, holdHistory = TRUE, getImp = getImpRfZ) -> Bor.rf
  #dfm <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(dfm[,getSelectedAttributes(Bor.rf)]))
  #dfm[[colm]] <- label

  #train the RF model
  modelRF.bor <- train(colm~., data=dfm, method="rf", trControl=control)

  pred.RF.bor = predict(modelRF.bor, newdata = dfm[ ,!(colnames(dfm) == st(colm))])
  print("Predictions for Column")
  print(colm)
  print(pred.RF.bor)

  table(pred.RF.bor,dfm$colm)
  acc.RF.bor = mean(pred.RF.bor==dfm$colm)
  print("Accuracy ")
  print(acc.RF.bor)
  print("Confusion Matrix")
  print(confusionMatrix(table(pred.RF.bor,dfm$colm)))

  output[,i] <- pred.RF.bor
  i = i+1
}
```

I am getting this error, and have checked everything in my code, and also similar questions here.

```
Error in model.frame.default(form = colm ~ ., data = dfm, na.action = na.fail) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'excel')
```

I can't share the data and all code, it's big and not needed I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking upstream to see if you have data attached.

Comment: I'm confused- I never indicated I have a question, only that I had the same problem and found a solution that worked for me. What should I do differently to be clear?